# Algorithm2e and sig-alternate-05-2015

Tags: acm

Getting this error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@xiiipt 
l.222 \@tempa\large
```

when I add `\usepackage{algorithm2e}` while using

```
\documentclass[10pt]{sig-alternate-05-2015}
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the definition of `sigalternate-05-2015.cls`. The macro `\@xiiipt` and others are never defined. The person that wrote the `10pt` option was not careful with the font size definitions.

I changed

```
\ifnum\ACM@basesize=10\relax
\newcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viiipt{9\p@}}
\newcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt{7\p@}%
\newcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiiipt{15\p@}}%
\newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xvpt{20\p@}}%
\newcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xixpt{22\p@}}%
\newcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xixpt{30\p@}}%
\newcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge30pt{36\p@}}
\fi
```

to

```
\ifnum\ACM@basesize=10\relax
  \newcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viiipt{9\p@}}
  \newcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt{7\p@}}
  \newcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{13\p@}{15\p@}}
  \newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{15\p@}{20\p@}}
  \newcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE{19\p@}{22\p@}}
  \newcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge{19\p@}{30\p@}}
  \newcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge{30\p@}{36\p@}}
\fi
```

and now it works (although I do not think this is the best solution).