# Error with new sig-alternate Undefined control sequence.\MT@val ->\@xiiipt

Tags: microtype, acm

When I try to compile using the new `sig-alternate` like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{sig-alternate}
```

`pdflatex` generates the document, but it gives some errors in lines 64 and 71:

```
Package microtype Warning: Could not parse font size `'
(microtype) in font set `basicmath' on input line 64.
! Undefined control sequence.
\MT@val ->\@xiiipt
```

and

```
Package microtype Warning: Could not parse font size `'
(microtype) in font set `basictext' on input line 71.
! Undefined control sequence.
\MT@val ->\@xiiipt
```

WHen I remove the `[10pt]` option it works fine. When I go to line 64 or 71 in the template, the lines are comments, so the error should be in other place.

Do you know why this can happen?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I wouldn't try using `microtype` with `sig-alternate`, which loads fonts in a non standard way.

Comment: `sig-alternate` is not standard. Please provide a link.

Comment: It's a bug in the `sig-alternate` class, which doesn't define various auxiliary macros used in the font size commands, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312560/7674). (You'd even get an error with just using a `\large` font.)